# How to print a message to stdout in ROS2?

Tags: ros, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am porting C++ code from ROS1 to ROS2. Apparently there was an `operator<<` automatically generated for messages in ROS1 but that's no longer (or not yet) available in ROS2. Is there a canonical (and easy) way to print a message, for example

```
   geometry_msgs::msg::Pose line_pose;
   RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "pose is " << line_pose);
```

When using the command line tools like `ros2 topic echo`, the same is  done behind the scenes. If I can just get a YAML representation and how to print that, I'd be happy, too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365776/how-to-print-a-message-to-stdout-in-ros2?/) by [fredBeauj](https://answers.ros.org/users/59109/fredbeauj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2020-11-17

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found out that recently (Sep 2020), a `to_yaml(msg, ostream)` function was added to ROS2 in response to this [issue](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/259). That means we will just have to wait a bit until that's available in a release. The core function is defined [here](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/pull/527/files#diff-cdc4e8b43fae0477c12bb259861be7b9908846f0bbf423d80464a42b0fb41548R66) and has this interface

```
void to_yaml(const @(message_typename) & msg,  std::ostream & out, size_t indentation = 0)
```

---

Originally posted by [fredBeauj](https://answers.ros.org/users/59109/fredbeauj/) with karma: 131 on 2020-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1